# plotly.js: why an area is calculated if all values are 0?

Tags: javascript, html, plotly.js, violin-plot

I have an array of values from 0-10 with and 20 groups in each. For some groups or categories all values are 0. When I use violin plot, there is an area calculated which is below 0 as in figure (? mark): [image]

But I want to get the following that I got from Seurat package VlnPlot:
[image]

Is there a way to overcome that problem?

Here is a part of java script code:

```
var my_violin = [];
var vln_layout = {};
var my_violin =[
{
    type:"violin",
    x:xvalues,
    y:my_categories,
    points:"all",
    pointpos:0,
    color:"black",
    width:0.75,
    marker:{color:"black",size:4},
    jitter:1,
    span:0,
    transforms:[
    {
        type:"groupby",
        groups:my_categories,
        styles:my_styles
    }
    ]
}
]

var vln_layout = {title: "my title",    xaxis:{showline: false,showgrid: false,zeroline: false,
    categoryorder: 'category ascending'}, yaxis: {showline: false,showgrid: false,zeroline:false},
    showlegend:true,legend:{traceorder:'normal',categoryorder:"ascending"}};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv2', my_violin, vln_layout, {showSendToCloud: false});
```

Comment: This might be a bug. Issues can be reported over at https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues

Comment: Thanks! I asked there as well here is the [link](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/3622)